# Spark union of dataframes does not give counts?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to union these dataframes ,i used G_ID is not Null or MCOM.T_ID is not null and used trim, the count does not come up ,its running since 1hr. there are only 3 tasks remaining out of 300 tasks.Please suggest how can i debug this ? is null causing issue how can i debug ?

[image]

[image]

```
 val table1 = spark.sql(""" SELECT  trim(C_ID) AS PC_ID FROM ab.CIDS WHERE 
  _UPDT_TM >= '2020-02-01 15:14:39.527'  """)

val table2 = spark.sql(""" SELECT trim(C_ID) AS PC_ID   FROM ab.MIDS MCOM INNER
 JOIN ab.VD_MBR VDBR
  ON Trim(MCOM.T_ID) = Trim(VDBR.T_ID) AND Trim(MCOM.G_ID) = Trim(VDBR.G_ID)
 AND Trim(MCOM.C123M_CD) IN ('BBB', 'AAA') WHERE MCOM._UPDT_TM >= '2020-02-01 15:14:39.527'
 AND Trim(VDBR.BB_CD) IN ('BBC') """)

var abc=table1.select("PC_ID").union(table2.select("PC_ID"))

even tried this --> filtered = abc.filter(row => !row.anyNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a data skew problem. Looking at the "Summary Metrics" it's clear that (at least) three quarters of your partitions are empty, so you are eliminating most of the potential parallelization that spark can provide for you.

Though it will cause a shuffle step (where data gets moved over the network between different executors), a `.repartition()` will help to balance the data across all of the partitions and create more valid units of work to be spread among the available cores. This would most likely provide a speedup of your `count()`.

As a rule of thumb, you'd likely want to call `.repartition()` with the parameter set to at least the number of cores in your cluster. Setting it higher will result in tasks getting completed more quickly (it's fun to watch the progress), though adds some management overhead to the overall time the job will take to run. If the tasks are too small (i.e. not enough data per partition), then sometime the scheduler gets confused and won't use the entire cluster either. On the whole, finding the right number of partitions is a balancing act.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have added alias to the column "C_ID" as "PC_ID". and after that you are looking for "C_ID".
2. And Union can be performed on same number of columns, your table1 and table2 has different in columns size.

   ```
   otherwise you will get:  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns
   ```

Please take care of these two scenario first.

Comment: thankyou , i added C_ID or PC_ID here for reference only,in my original query this is correctly mentioned